# How can I create an annotation processor that processes a Local Variable?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to create an annotation for a local variable. I know that I can't retain the annotation in the generated bytecode, but I should be able to have access to the information at compile time by doing something like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Junk {
  String value();
}
```

only, this doesn't get processed by apt, or javac when I specify a ProcessorFactory that has "Junk" in it's supported types in the following:

```
class JunkTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @Junk String tmp = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}
```

It will however work when I move the @Junk annotation before `public static`

Thoughts and or workarounds?

Comment: curious: what do you want to do with local variables annotated with @Junk?

Comment: @Junk is obviously just an example, but eventually I'd like to do code generation from the real annotation.

Comment: yes, but if you do that, you are manipulating code inside the method, right? that seems pretty difficult in annotation processor.

Comment: I want to pull out some information at compile time, to create a static object with information pertinent at runtime.

Comment: @irreputable - you can't manipulate the existing code, but you can generate new code based on the annotation.

Comment: @Andrew - since you mention javac, are you using JDK 1.6?

Comment: new code in a new method, based on a local variable in another method? if this is top secret project, you don't have to explain. but it is very curious.

Comment: @irreputable The annotation processor should pull out all the @Junk annotations on local variables in the source tree, and create a new java file that lists them all, and their properties as a static array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did some quick tests and searched a little, and it's looking like hooking into `LOCAL_VARIABLE` isn't really supported...yet:

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=775449
http://www.cs.rice.edu/~mgricken/research/laptjavac/
https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/

Could be totally wrong, but that's how it's looking...

Comment: That has been my findings as well. I'm not sure if there are any workarounds other than a new compiler such as laptjavac (well, patched). 

I've also seen that `@SuppressWarnings`, which according to Effective Java work as `LOCAL_VARIABLE` annotations, are sort of special cased in javac, so it's not looking good.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the [Type Annotations Specification (JSR 308)](https://checkerframework.org/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-design.html), will hopefully address this subject in the future ([JDK 8](http://jdk8.java.net/type-annotations/) ?).

Comment: Correct.  As of Java 8, local variable annotations are stored in the classfile.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 8, local variable annotations are stored in the classfile.

A standard Java annotation processor does not process the bodies of methods.
However, the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) enables you to write an annotation processor that processes every annotation including on local variables.  Its annotation processors can even examine every statement of the program, whether annotated or not.