# Can I get the instance in a method using Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I just started using Guice so my understanding could be completely wrong.

I have an interface `Foo` and an implmentation `FooImp`

I have used the following code in my module to inject it:

```
bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith("Foo").toInstance(foo);  // foo is an instance of FooImp
```

Then I guess now in my code wherever a `Foo` instance with a name annotation of "Foo" will be replaced by `foo`?

```
@Named("Foo")
Foo fooInst;   // fooInst will be foo at runtime?
```

If I'm right, how can I achieve this:

```
public Foo doSomething() {  // for some reason there must be no arguments
    @Named("Foo")
    Foo fooInst;   // injecting here seems not allowed...?
    fooInst.do();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are assuming is not completely right: Guice is used for dependency injection, which means that you can inject some interface/class into the constructor of another class.

Lets say you have an interface `Foo` and it's implementation `FooImpl`. Then you also have a class `Bar` which depends on an implementation of `Foo`.

```
public class Bar {

    private Foo foo;

    @Inject
    public Bar(@Named("foo") Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    //some other methods
}
```

In your Guice-module you have to write

```
bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Foo")).toInstance(foo);
//let's say this is part of the module MyModule extends AbstractModule
```

Once you set this up, you can make a main-method where you create an object by using Guice's `Injector`-class. Like so:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
Bar bar = injector.getInstance(Bar.class);
//do something with bar
```

Hope this helped you with it. If you have more questions, feel free to ask me!

Hint: check the website of [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), watch the video overthere and read the wiki carefully. Guice is a really great tool, but you need to do some study before you use it.
Good luck!

---

Addition: In my opinion using `@Named` is a bad codestyle. You can better define your own annotations. For example:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface FooAnnotation {
}
```

Then replace `@Named("foo")` by `@FooAnnotation` in the `Bar` class and replace `Names.named("Foo")` by `FooAnnotation.class` in your module.

Comment: Clear and helpful answer. Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly you cannot place annotations on local variables. This limitation comes from Java and not from Guice. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285652/how-can-i-create-an-annotation-processor-that-processes-a-local-variable/13878403#13878403) there is hope that we get this feature in future Java versions.

But please note that even if this would work it wouldn't be a good practice. The idea of dependency injection is the ability to change dependencies from outside of a class. A local variable does not fit into this because it cannot be changed from outside the class.

Comment: I didn't take this as the answer as Rvan's helps more. However still very helpful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct--you can only inject into the constructor, or into a field. It's standard practice to keep the instances as fields, which also allows you to swap in your own implementations for testing.

If you need to produce a new instance every time a method is called, you can use a `Provider`. For any given binding for `Foo` (or `@Baz Foo`), `Provider<Foo>` (or `@Baz Provider<Foo>`) is [bound automatically](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html) without any extra code needed.

```
public class Bar {
  private Provider<Foo> fooProvider;

  @Inject
  public Bar(@Named("foo") Provider<Foo> fooProvider) {
    this.fooProvider = fooProvider;
  }

  public doSomething() {
    Foo foo = fooProvider.get();
  }
}
```

Of course, the way you have it with `bind(...).toInstance(...)`, it will always be the same instance anyway, but should you need a new instance for every run of a method this is your best choice.

Comment: You answered my question just after I accepted another...I'll check that later. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct with your remark about new instance and always same instance. What I do most of the time is this: `bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(...).to(FooImp.class)`. Usually this is used. Using a provider is more commonly used when complex classes are involved.